# Wait until element is not clickable

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java

I have online text editor page. There are two buttons: "Save" and "Close".

"Save" - is clickable, when changes are not saved:

```
<button class="btn save-btn" title="Save content">Save</button>
```

"Save" - is not clickable, when there are no changes:

```
<button class="btn save-btn" title="Save content" disabled="">Save</button>
```

Close button is always clickable.

I need to have following test:

- Click on Save
- Wait until changes are saved (Save button is not
  clickable)
- Click Close

How to check, whether "Save" button is not clickable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When element becomes not clickable this will also probably be accompanied by additional UI change, for example new class "inactive" will be added to the Save button classes.
If so you can do:

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".save-btn.inactive"));
```

Update:
If no additional css class is added, but the `disabled=""` attribute only present when disabled, this should work too

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".save-btn[disabled='']"));
```

If Saving takes more time, than your default waiting time (the time WebDriver waits for elements to appear), you can set ImplicitlyWait to some higher value, and then set it back to what was your default

```
int defaultTimeout = driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait;
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100));
//find the disabled button in a preferred manner
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(defaultTimeout));
```

Comment: If button is not clickable, there is an attribute `disabled=""`, without `disabled='true'`

Comment: Updated accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You can use FluentWait, and wait for ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable.

Create fluent wait with timeout and pooling which you need:

```
FluentWait wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
                .pollingEvery(pooling, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .withTimeout(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class)
                .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
                .withMessage(message);
```

**Edit:**
And then specify your custom function:

```
Function<WebDriver, Boolean> notEnabled = new Function<WebDriver, Boolean>() {
    public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
    return !driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Save']")).isEnabled();
    }
};
```

And use it:

```
wait.until(notEnabled);
```

This should loop until isEnabled() return false, or until FluentWait timeouts.

Read for example:

[Understand Webdriver Fluent Wait with Examples](https://www.techbeamers.com/webdriver-fluent-wait-command-examples/)

[WebDriver Implicit, Explicit and Fluent Wait Examples](https://www.testingexcellence.com/webdriver-explicit-implicit-fluent-wait/)

Comment: Operator '!' cannot be applied to 'org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition<org.openqa.selenium.WebElement>'

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this without delving into FluentWait is to just use a while loop. Because disabled is being added to the button, it means we can use WebDriver's isEnabled method, and just loop until it returns false.

```
    int attempts = 0;
    int maxAttempts = 10;
    boolean buttonDisabled = false;

    while(attempts++ <= maxAttempts) {
        if(!driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Save']")).isEnabled()) {
            buttonDisabled = true;
            break;
        } else {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
    }

    if(buttonDisabled) {
        // Your success code
    } else {
        // Your failure code
    }
```

Not super pretty, but hopefully enough to demonstrate a possible solution.